# Password management service - Web, iPhone and iPad - any ideas?

Tags: security, iphone, passwords, ipad

I'm looking for a password management service that's based in the cloud, has a web, iPhone and iPad app, and is secure.

I don't mind paying a bit for the apps but I'd like something without a monthly fee.

Any ideas?

Comment: Personal opinion: keeping your passwords on someone else's server (even if it properly encrypts on your end) is asking for trouble. If there's ANYTHING wrong with their encryption algorithm, then the attacker knows where to go to get passwords for a LOT of people.

Answer (score 3):

For me [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/) is brilliant.

It encrypts your passwords locally and only the master password hash is stored by LastPass.

Their Premium version is available on the iPhone & iPad and costs only $1 a month.

I would highly recommend it - or at least giving it a trial.